# How to write a dictionary along with a dataframe into excel

Tags: excel, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that defines a customer:

```
Customer
    role:blah
    phonenumber:111-222-3333
    company:blahblah
    branch:blahblahblah
```

And I have a dataframe of all the shipping information that has about 10 columns of information. What I want to accomplish is to write into a worksheet first the customer information that I already matched and then underneath it the dataframe with headers and then do the same thing for the next customer underneath the last. Each sheet is defined by role so there aren't that many customers showing up on the same sheet.

I figured out how to write the dataframes into the workbook according to the role worksheets, but I haven't been able to print out the dictionary above it. Can you guys help me out?

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
row_count = dict()    
for ID in df['PhoneNumber']:
    sheet_name_var = str(self.match_ID2role(ID))
    #count the row position for each df in each sheet
    df_length = len(df)
    try:
        row_count[sheet_name_var]+=1
    except:
        row_count[sheet_name_var]=1
    #add the customer dictionary somehow
    #####*****************#########
    row_count[sheet_name_var]+=1
    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet_name_var,startrow=row_count[sheet_name_var])
```

Example of output:

```
James
    role: blah
    phonenumber:999-888-7777
    company: blahblah
    branch: blahblahblah

Timestamp    PhoneNumber    Call_duration    Product   
2016-01-01   999-888-7777   12.34            beachballs

Bobby
    role: bla
    phonenumber: 666-444-5555
    company: blebla
    branch: bleblabloop

Timestamp    PhoneNumber    Call_duration    Product   
2016-01-01   666-444-5555   35.24            applies
```